# Where can I get Ruby, GraphViz and Dot hosted?

Tags: ruby, hosting, sinatra, heroku, graphviz

I want to find some hosting for a small Ruby (Sinatra) app that uses Graphviz and Dot.

Heroku is usually my favorite because it's a) Free, b) Simple, and c) Scalable. Heroku doesn't do Graphviz and Dot, so I'm looking for an alternative. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've been very happy with [bluehost.com](http://www.bluehost.com/).  They support ruby/rails, etc. and while they do not provide graphviz or dot 'out-of-the-box,' they provide shell accounts.  I've worked with Graphviz and dot before on a different, but similar, system before.  If you're willing to take a crack at it from a bash prompt, bluehost would be more that acceptable.

They also have fantastic customer support.  (And no, I'm not affiliated with them at all.  Just a customer.)

Answer (score 2):

Dreamhost seems to allow you to install Graphviz:

> http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Graphviz

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to deal with a stripped down 'Viz api, Google Charts API [now supports GraphViz experimentally](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/graphviz.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest moving to a VPS.  I use [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/), and they have plans starting at $20 a month.

Comment: +1  I've been using Slicehost for years now, and they're by far the best bang for your buck.

Answer (score 1):

Now that Heroku's Cedar stack supports [Custom Buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) you could probably create a custom buildpack to use Graphviz and Dot. It looks like someone created one [here](https://github.com/stigkj/heroku-buildpack-graphviz). Maybe give it a shot.